# XCode keeps hanging and I have to force quit

Tags: macos, xcode

I have an iMac running High Sierra and Xcode version 10.1. I've recently started using Xcode a lot and it keeps hanging on me. I'll do something and the beachball appears. I eventually have to force quit Xcode. I'll restart Xcode and repeat the process but it'll work the 2nd time. This has been happening frequently. How do I stop Xcode from hanging so much?

Comment: When's the last time you rebooted your Mac? If a reboot doesn't make any difference, then I'd use [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to completely uninstall Xcode.app and all it's associated files, reboot the Mac and reinstall Xcode.

Comment: I reboots about 2 days ago.

Comment: and it has enough resources ? CPU/RAM ? if you do not know what to do or what the problem is you can remove and reinstall, but I doubt that will help. I would try to find out in the console why it hangs and fix that.

Comment: I have 16 Gigs of RAM and Xcode is about all that is running.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Next time it hangs I check the console.

Comment: I did not get your comment automatically, you forgot to use @name to address specific person

Comment: @Buscar yes i forgot to address my message.  sorry about that.

Comment: @ Buscar웃 How do I make the character at end of your name?  I just copied it for this message.